# Get Windows "codename"

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Is there a PowerShell command that will retrieve the Windows "codename"?

10.0.19042 has a "codename" of "20H2".

Is there a Get-CimInstance class (or other command) that contains "20H2"?

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.3.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with 20H2, you can find this value in the registry key
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
In the DisplayVersion value.

```
(Get-Item "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").GetValue('DisplayVersion')
```

Comment: This works. If this is a "Windows-only" thing, then querying the registry will probably work, but I would like to get this from a PowerShell object.

Comment: Or, more succinctly (as in the duplicate): `Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' DisplayVersion` @lit: It is a Windows-only thing, and given the name of the registry value, calling this piece of information _display version_ is probably apt. It is unfortunate that `$PSVersionTable` doesn't contain this information. It also uses a legacy value for the `OS` property (e.g. `Microsoft Windows 10.0.2262` on Windows 11(!)), and doesn't report the underlying .NET version. May be worth opening a feature request at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues

Comment: @mklement0, while it might be helpful to have OS information, the "codename," and version of .Net installed in `$PSVersionTable`, they are not actually about PowerShell. I think I might have found your earlier answer if it used the Microsoft terminology "codename."

Comment: releaseid and ubr (monthly version) are in that key as well, although releaseid has been saying 2009 for a while

Comment: @lit, to me "codename" (code name) has a connotation of secrecy, and in the context of Microsoft specifically, it has a different meaning (emphasis added): "Microsoft codenames are given by Microsoft to products it has in development _before these products are given the names by which they appear on store shelves_." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_codenames, so "display name", while not ideal, seems like the better choice.

Comment: @lit, as for `$PSVersionTable`: since it already contains OS information, and this information is meant to be used in bug reports, it makes sense to make it report _accurate_ information, not frozen values for backward compatibility.

Comment: @lit, sorry, I meant to say "display _version_" earlier, not "display _name_".

Comment: As for `$PSVersionTable` improvements: I've created [GitHub issue #19121](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19121).

Answer (score 0):

I verified this on Win11 22H2, in Windows PowerShell 5.1:

```
gin | select OSDisplayVersion | fl
```

Comment: As an aside: to print the _value_ of the property only, use `gin | select -ExpandProperty OSDisplayVersion` or simply `(gin).OSDisplayVersion`

Comment: This does not work on Windows 10 20H2 using PowerShell 5.1 or 7.3. `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.2546]`

Comment: Yes, that cmdlet came out after that release I think. In that case, you won't find a pure PS solution for that old version, only the reg key above.

Comment: I've opened [GitHub issue #19120](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19120) to ask that the property be added to PowerShell Core too.